# Supply default default value in NHibernate mapping for unused columns

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

My domain object doesn't use 2 non-nullable columns from a table in the database.  Both of the columns are Guids.  Is there a way I can supply a default value for these columns in my mapping file so that I'm able to save my domain object back to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Provide your own <sql-insert> in the hbm.xml file. Unfortunately this forces you to take control of all the insert logic.
- Map the columns to private fields within the object that aren't exposed and set the guids when you create a new instance. NHibernate can then save these fields back when inserting. You can also mark the mappings as update="false" so that they're only ever inserted.
- Add default values for those columns in the database schema.

Comment: Another option would be using an eventlistener..I do this for things such as datecreated/dateupdated. This would encapsulate the logic for applying the default values and allow you to share it across multiple entities by having them implement a common interface.